# Require 100% code coverage for ASP.NET Core web application controllers in Azure DevOps build pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, code-coverage, xunit, coverlet

In our project we have a requirement that all controller methods should have at least one test.

Our build fails if we have a test that fails but right now we are using this guide to check code coverage manually:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage?tabs=windows#generate-reports

Basically this means running two commands:

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:CoverletOutput="Path\To\TestProject\TestResults\coverage.cobertura.xml"

reportgenerator "-reports:Path\To\TestProject\TestResults\coverage.cobertura.xml" "-targetdir:coveragereport" -reporttypes:Html
```

Note: If you run `dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"` you can get a `coverage.cobertura.xml` file but if you use msbuild with `/p:CollectCoverage=true` you will have to add the package `dotnet add package coverlet.msbuild` to the test project once.

https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/issues/201

We then get a report like this:

[image]

Our line coverage in this case is not great but our controllers have 100% line coverage. It would be OK to check that a specific namespace like `Project.Web.Controllers` has 100% line coverage.

We can not use the normal code coverage results to fail a build since we only want to fail a build if controllers are not tested.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-code-coverage-results?view=azure-devops

https://gunnarpeipman.com/azure-devops-check-code-coverage/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60894835/3850405

Is there any way to do this nicely or do we need to read the `coverage.cobertura.xml` file and look at `<class name="Project.Web.Controllers` for example?

Comment: You can try to add `--filter` option to `dotnet test` command. For example: If you are using the MSTest framework, then you can use the `ClassName` property like this: `dotnet test --filter ClassName=classA | ClassName=classB`. Specify all test classes under `Project.Web.Controllers` namespace in the filter. Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#filter-option-details) you can refer to.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT That only filters the tests that should be ran, not actual code coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a command for it!

The key was using `/p:Include="[*]Project.Web.Controllers.*" /p:Threshold=100 /p:ThresholdType=line`

Complete command:

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:Include="[*]Project.Web.Controllers.*" /p:Threshold=100 /p:ThresholdType=line
```

https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/blob/master/Documentation/MSBuildIntegration.md

Pass:

[image]

Fail:

[image]